# Finding a particular type of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, soft-question, uniform-convergence

For every bounded  function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ , which is dis-continuous at at most countably many points of its domain ; can we find a sequence of real-valued functions $\{f_n\}$ with  domain $[a,b]$ such that each $f_n$ is dis-continuous at only finitely many points of its domain and $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ ? If such a sequence of functions can not be found for every $f$ , can we impose some extra condition on $f$ such that such a sequence can be found ?

( For such functions $f$ , since each $f_n$ is easily shown to be Riemann-integrable , we can conclude , due to uniform convergence , that $f$ is Riemann integrable )

Comment: If $f$ is not bounded, It is clearly impossible to find such a sequence $f_n$. First I suppose you must assume $f$ bounded.

Comment: @foo90 : Yes , I do need $f$ to be bounded

Answer (score 2):

No. Put $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $A=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, $f|A=1$ and $f|[0,1]\setminus A=0$. Then the function $f$ is discontinuous at each point of the set $A$ and is continuous at each point of the set $[0,1]\setminus A$. Moreover, if $g:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is a function such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<1/3$ for each $x\in [0,1]$ then the function $g$ is discontinuous at each point of the set $A$ too.

Comment: This doesn't change the validity of this counter-example, but your function $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Nice simple counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bounded Variation (also called "rectifiable") is the condition you want on $f$.  It suffices to consider $f$ monotone and bounded, since any BV function is a difference of two monotone ones, and the set of functions approximable as required in the problem statement is closed under addition.

For $f$ monotone and bounded, the set of discontinuities is countable and sum of the jumps at discontinuities finite. If the jumps are $J_1, J_2, \dots $ then $\sum |J_i|$ is absolutely convergent. Cutting off the sum at $n$ terms with less than $\epsilon$ of jumping left in the "tail" of the series, fit a function to $f$ that equals it around the first $n$ jumps, is within $\epsilon$ everywhere, and bridges the jumps with index higher than $n$ by linear interpolation over a very short interval near the discontinuity.

The details are more complex than this because of the possibility that the set of points of discontinuity has limit points.  Nevertheless I think the complications can be overcome and the essential point is bounded variation.  If I have time I will write out a fuller argument.

Comment: Bounded variation in a subdomain containing all the points of discontinuity, or maybe even bounded total jump discontinuity, would be more precise conditions. The function can oscillate all it wants on intervals where it is continuous, and this does not impede uniform continuous approximation.